# How to make this bubble type widget in flutter which depicts a certain message on tap?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I need help with this widget .

[image]

Comment: please provide more information.

Answer (score 2):

Try this package [popover 0.2.6+3](https://pub.dev/packages/popover)

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to view the flutter animated popUp
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsyjMrZa5OU

Comment: In your case the animation is simple and just a pop-up, so you don't need to wrap the gesture detector to control further buttons just use the animation.